# How to explicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selectlist

I am trying to create a new SelectList and return it via `return Acctlist.ToList<SelectListItem>();` statement, but can't because of the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'

```
        private SelectList RemoveCustomersWithoutSites(SelectList CustomerSelectList)
    {
        // Update the Account Number dropdown in the SafeContacts pages to only include accounts that have at least one monitored location in Stages.
        SelectList CustList = null;
        List<SelectListItem> Acctlist = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (SelectListItem AcntNumber in CustomerSelectList.Items){
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> siteList = null;
            siteList = objAPICommon.GetSites(AcntNumber.ToString());

            // Add this Account if it has a site
            if (siteList != null && siteList.Count() > 0)
            {
                SelectListItem item;
                item = new SelectListItem { Text = AcntNumber.Text, Value = AcntNumber.Value };
                Acctlist.Add(item);
            }
        }

        return ***Acctlist.ToList<SelectListItem>()***;
    }
```

How should I Cast or Convert `Acctlist` into a `SelectList` please? Thank you.

Comment: `return new SelectList(AcctList);`

Comment: What would be the point? `SelectList` is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` but not the other way around. And all that's needed for the `DropDownListFor()` method is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. Using new SelectList(...)` to create an identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one is just pointless extra overhead. Just make you method `private IEnumerable<SelectListItem>RemoveCustomersWithoutSites(....)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new `SelectList` with the items:

```
new SelectList(items)
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed my return statement to SelectList CustomerSelectList1 = new SelectList(Acctlist, "customer_number", "cust_name");